# htaccess rewrite to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

How to rewrite all urls like :

www.domain.com/en/about-us, 
www.domain.com/en/articles/12/article-title

to

uk.domain.com/en/about-us,
uk.domain.com/en/articles/12/article-title

I have tried something like this, but it rewrites all urls to uk.domain.com:
for example:

www.domain.com/en/about-us rewrites always to uk.domain.com, but no to uk.domain.com/en/about-us

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ http://uk.domain.com [R,L]
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewrtieEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ http://uk.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI}  [L,NE,R=301]
```